# parse CSV file into dictionary with multiple values per key

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I want to create a simple config CSV file for my python script that will be loaded into a dictionary.
Every line should represent a dictionary key with a list of values.

The structure will look like this:

```
key, value1, value2, value3, value4
key, value1, value2, value3, value4
key, value1, value2, value3, value4
```

A print (list) looks like this:

['key,value1,value2,value3,value4','key,value1,value2,value3,value4','key,value1,value2,value3,value4']

My function for reading input file gives me back a list with element per line. Here I try to build the dictionary with the split string function in a loop. But I cannot get the syntax right. I have found some similar examples, but they don't seem to work in python 3.

```
result = dict(line.split(",")[0],[line.split(",")[1:] for line in list)
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dict comprehension.
Oh, and try to avoid calling variables the same name as built-ins (so I've called it `lst` instead):

```
result = {line.split(',')[0]: line.split(',')[1:] for line in lst}
```